# AngularDart: 'nGBootstrap is not defined' error

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to run this simple code from [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/tree/master/Chapter_01)

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
  void main() {
    ngBootstrap();
  }
```

But i recieve this error:

```
The function 'ngBootstrap' is not defined
```

Any idea about what's happening? I already tried 'pub get'.

Comment: Are you using angular.dart from git?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lastest angular version is 0.9.11.
So, you must use `ngDynamicApp().addModule(new MyAppModule()).run();` instead of `ngBootstrap(module: new MyAppModule());`, 
and add `import 'package:angular/angular_dynamic.dart';` in your main.dart.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Any idea why this isn't mentioned under 'Breaking Changes' in the changelog?

Answer (score 5):

Lastest angular version is 0.10.0.

So, now you must use `applicationFactory().addModule(new MyAppModule()).run();` instead of `ngDynamicApp().addModule(new MyAppModule()).run();`, 
and always add import `'package:angular/angular_dynamic.dart';` in your main.dart.

Be careful, many thing has changed, like we use `Component` without `@`... etc.

Comment: Importing angular_dynamic gives me an error saying `Target URI does nor exists` and my angular version is 0.10.0. I had to import `package:angular/application_factory.dart`, then it worked.